# I upgraded my project from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2015 but i is there any need to upgrade the msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am upgrading my project from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2015
please tell me is there any need to upgraded the ms-build project.

Comment: This should have happen along with the VS install.  Did it not or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: @Bharat D, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved your issue? If not, Please let me know the latest information about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to upgrade project created in earlier versions of VS this may help you:

- In VS, on the File menu, click Open and then click Project/Solution,
  Web Site, or File, depending on the kind of project you are
  upgrading.
- In the Open Project dialog box, select a project file, and then click
  Open. If VS detects that the project or file was created in an earlier version of Visual Studio, the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard opens.
- Complete the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard.

[Refrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185327(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> is there any need to upgraded the ms-build project?

The answer is No. That because since start with Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio team made a number of exciting changes to MSBuild for Visual Studio 2013. Now t**he 2013 version of MSBuild will ship as a part of Visual Studio instead of the .NET Framework**. See this blog [MSBuild is now part of Visual Studio!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/) for more detail info.

You can find the MSBuild.exe from the directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`

Since it ships as a part of Visual Studio 2013, just as Michael said, **MSBuild upgrade should happen with the VS installation**. So you do not need to upgrade the MSBuild separately.

Hope this helps.